# About DateTime widget with style SWT.CALENDAR

Tags: java, datetime, swt

How can  we detect whether user clicked (using mouse) on month or day or year on `DateTime` with style `SWT.CALENDAR`.

Comment: Can you explain the use-case for us? Why do you need to know what exactly the user clicked on rather than just listen for click events in general and then poll the date from the widget?

Comment: Actual purpose was to get the selected date and dispose the calendar popup for single click on date, but on implementing this the problem 
was the calendar gets disposed even when we click on the year or month, however i have implemented it myself thanks all, for your respose

Comment: Please post your solution here, so others can benefit from it as well.

Comment: if(calendarWidget.getYear() == defaultYear && calendarWidget.getMonth() == defaultMonth)
{
//here i am getting the selected date and saving it                  
defaultYear = calendarWidget.getYear();
defaultMonth = calendarWidget.getMonth();
shell.dispose();
}
else
{
defaultYear = calendarWidget.getYear();
defaultMonth = calendarWidget.getMonth(); 
}
here default month and year are the default selected date in calendar widget.

Comment: Please use the "Your answer" field at the bottom of the page. This will allow us to upvote your answer and yourself to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actual purpose was to get the selected date and dispose the calendar popup for single click on date, but on implementing this the problem was the
calendar gets disposed even when we click on the year or month, however i have implemented it myself thanks all for your respose

```
if(calendarWidget.getYear() == defaultYear && calendarWidget.getMonth() == defaultMonth)
{
    //here i am getting the selected date and saving it
    defaultYear = calendarWidget.getYear();
    defaultMonth = calendarWidget.getMonth();
    shell.dispose();
}
else
{
    defaultYear = calendarWidget.getYear();
    defaultMonth = calendarWidget.getMonth();
}
```

here default month and year are the default selected date in calendar widget.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Shiva answer I've added one more condition.
If you choose a day from another month than current, it will hide popup. Example:
You see popup with March and you select one of the first days of April.

```
if((calendar.getYear() == defaultYear && calendar.getMonth() == defaultMonth) ||
                    (calendar.getYear() == defaultYear && calendar.getMonth() != defaultMonth && calendar.getDay() != defaultDay))
            {
                //here i am getting the selected date and saving it
                defaultYear = calendar.getYear();
                defaultMonth = calendar.getMonth();
                defaultDay = calendar.getDay();
                popup.dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                defaultYear = calendar.getYear();
                defaultMonth = calendar.getMonth();
                defaultDay = calendar.getDay();
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you mean `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.DateTime` it inherit `addMouseListener`.

`MouseListener` interface has method:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt)
```

and [MouseEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html) has methods:

```
getX()
getY()
```

So you can get relative position of mouse, when it is clicked and calculate on which element it is, depending on component properties.

Comment: `DateTime` use a native control to display the calendar (for example `NSDatePicker` on Mac OSX). There is no way to identify the part of the native control from the X, Y position.

Comment: You can check what system you're runing on and adjust result to that.

Comment: @KonradOliwer Do you really want to go down that road? This would mean having a separate implementation for each OS (even OS versions) and you'd have to potentially update it every time a new OS version comes along.

Comment: Many aplications have requiraments for compatibility with selected OS. So it's not so bad. I belive hard way is better then no way.